# PSD to Bootstrap3 convert

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to convert a PSD file to Bootstrap3. Bootstrap3 container size is 1140px and padding between column is 30px. But Container of the psd is 1280px and padding between column is 60px. Is it possible to do it using bootstrap3? or need to write custom css? Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [Bootstrap Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/),. There you scroll down to "Grid system" and change the `@grid-gutter-width` to your padding.

One section further at "Container sizes", you can change `@container-large-desktop` to your container size.

Then download your custom Bootstrap build.